# Hausdorff–Young inequality

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The Hausdorff–Young inequality says that If $ f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d), \quad 1\leq p\leq 2$ then
\begin{equation*}
 \| \hat{f}\|_{L^{p'}(\mathbb{R})}\leq \|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}, \quad \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1.
\end{equation*}
where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$.

I would like to know if it is possibile, by assuming some hypothesis on function $f$, to get for $p>2$, $ \|\hat{f}\|_{L^{p'}(\mathbb{R})}$ bounded.

In other words, it is reasonable to have a function $f$ such that $\hat{f}$ is in $L^{p'},\ p'<2$?

Comment: It is certainly true for some functions $f$. For example, if $f$ is a Schwartz function, then $\hat f$ is again a Schwartz function, which means that it is in $L^p$ for all $p\in [1,\infty]$. The question is what kind of conditions you are looking for.

Comment: $f$ is a data and I need to understand the hypothesis to put on it. 
I have
$\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} | \xi^{\alpha}\hat{f}(\xi)|^q d\xi\bigg)^{\frac{1}{q}} = \|\widehat{(-\Delta)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}f}\|_{L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^{d})}=\|\widehat{D^{\alpha}f}\|_{L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^{d})}$
where $D^\alpha:=(-\Delta)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}: H^{\alpha, q}(\R^{d})\to L^{q}(\R^{d})$
and $H^{\alpha, q}(\R^{d})$ is the Bessel space and $\widehat{D^{\alpha}}$ is the fourier transform of  $D^{\alpha}$. 
I want to control $\|\widehat{D^{\alpha}f}\|_{L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^{d})}$ but I can't use H-Y inequality.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you need additional derivatives to control the $L^q$ norm of a Fourier transform with $q<2$.

An easy way to get a sufficient condition is the following. Let $\langle \xi\rangle := (1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}$ and $n>d\,(\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{2})$. Then by Hölder's inequality
$$
\|\widehat f\|_{L^q(\Bbb R^d)} = \|\langle \xi\rangle^{-n}\langle \xi\rangle^{n}\widehat f\|_{L^q(\Bbb R^d)} ≤ C_{n,q}\, \|\langle \xi\rangle^n\widehat f\|_{L^2(\Bbb R^d)}
$$
where $C_{n,q} = \|\langle \xi\rangle^{-n}\|_{L^\frac{2\,q}{2-q}(\Bbb R^d)} < \infty$ with our choice of $n$. Now by Plancherel Theorem,
$$
\|\langle \xi\rangle^n\widehat f\|_{L^2(\Bbb R^d)} = \|(1-\Delta)^{n/2}f\|_{L^2(\Bbb R^d)} = \|f\|_{H^n}
$$
so that
$$
\|\widehat f\|_{L^q(\Bbb R^d)} ≤ C_{n,q}\,\|f\|_{H^n}
$$

A particular case is the case $q=1$, which is lot more studied. A sufficient condition to have $\widehat f∈L^1$ is $f∈ H^n$ with $n>d/2$. A slightly sharper condition in this case is $f∈B^{d/2}_{2,1}$ (where $B^s_{p,q}$ are the Besov spaces). Another easy condition is $\widehat f ≥ 0$ and $f$ continuous, since in this case $\|f\|_{L^1} = \int_{\Bbb R^d} f = \widehat{f}(0)$. A lot more different sufficient conditions of different kind can be found in [1].

As proved for example in [2], to have derivatives is a necessary condition (at least in dimension $d>1$) since if $\widehat f ∈ L^1$ then its radial part $f_0$ satisfies $f_0 ∈ C^{(d-1)/2}(0,\infty)$.

---

[1] Liflyand, Samko, Trigub, *The Wiener algebra of absolutely convergent Fourier integrals: an overview*

[2] Liflyand, *Necessary Conditions for Integrability of the Fourier Transform*

Comment: What is the norm $\| \cdot \|_{H^n}$?

Comment: The one written in Equation 2 ...

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer and your references. They have been very useful. Just one more question: what is the operator $(1-\Delta)$?

Comment: And is the norm $\| f \|_{H^n}$ equivalent to the $L^2$ norm of $D^{n} f$ i.e.: $\| f \|_{H^n} = \| D^{n} f \|_{L^2}$

Comment: No, you need to add the $L^2$ norm of $f$

Comment: So $\| f\|_{H^n} = \| f\|_{L^2} + \|D^n f \|_{L^2}$?

Comment: Yes, that's an equivalent norm. You can define $(1-\Delta)$ as the Fourier multiplier by $(1+|x|^2)$. And $(1+|x|^2)^n$ is equivalent to $(1+|x|^{2n})$. But if you have many questions, you should rather ask your own question instead of writing comments ...